# Request or query permissions to access the file system from input type="file" after being denied in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, permissions, filesystems

When a user denies access to the fileSystem (files, camera, photos, videos) on an android **mobile** through the browser (Chrome and Firefox) it doesn't react anymore, and it seems broken.

I would like to notify the user somehow that he has to grant access or change the settings. This could happen in two ways:

1. Query the permissions and if it's not granted give a warning message to change the settings;
2. Request permission from the code prompting again the access popup;

I tried using [`fileHandle.queryPermission(options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemHandle/queryPermission) but it's not compatible with Firefox APIs and anyway couldn't make it work on Chrome and also tried [`Permission.query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query) but it doesn't seem to have the file-system access I need.

I'd need a solution that would be cross-browsers on mobiles.

Here you have a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-system-permissions-4g3i44?file=/src/App.tsx) to play around from your mobile to see what works and what doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you tried or not, but you could pass the "persistent-storage" string as value for the `name` parameter while using the `navigator.permissions.query` API.

This will give you the current Permission object for the device storage, and you could check whether it is `granted`, `prompted` or `denied`.

```js
const askForPermissions = async () => {
  try {
    const storagePermission = await navigator.permissions.query({
      name: "persistent-storage"
    });

    if (storagePermission.state === "granted")
      console.log("All good, permission granted!");
    if (storagePermission.state === "prompt")
      console.log("Prompt for permissions!");
    if (storagePermission.state === "denied")
      console.log("Ouch, you don't have permissions!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while fetching storage permissions: ", error.message);
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return <input id="request" type="file" onClick={askForPermissions} />;
}
```

I tried it rejecting the prompt for storage permissions on Firefox mobile and Chrome and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoGhiani for your answer. I gave it a try but as I suspected `"persistent-storage"` is not the right type of access we're looking for. It seems it refers to persisting some memory, maybe a local storage type of memory, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.